# correct scss code to get the color shown on the screen

Tags: html, css, sass

I am facing an issue when building my scss files to css. The color is not displaying at screen.

This is my scss code:

```
$--base-color-secondary-text-white: #e8e8e8

div {
    >div.oj-select-choice {
        border-bottom: .08rem solid var(--base-color-secondary-text-white) !important;
    }
}
```

How can I correct my code to get the color applied and shown on my screen?

Comment: You're missing a closing semi-colon after the variable definition.

Comment: where please I checked all semi-colons are closed

Comment: After `#e8e8e8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By placing this `var(--base-color-secondary-text-white)` the browser is expecting a CSS Variable, not an SCSS Variable provided in post compile. I would suggest for starters to improve readability and not use CSS Var syntax for SCSS vars. However if you simply replace;

`var(--base-color-secondary-text-white)`
with
`$--base-color-secondary-text-white` in your scss it should work....after you add a semicolon at the end of the scss var.